# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, linq, repositorylookupedit

**Thrown Exception**

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1[SalesWithLinq.DAL.UnitName]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SalesWithLinq.DAL.UnitName]'.'

---

I want to add unit name inside repository lookUpEdit and save it once i leave the cell
the data is successfully saved in data base but when reach casting line the exception thrown

---

```
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit repoUOM = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit(); // field of form class
```

```
repoUOM.DisplayMember = "Name"; // inside form load event
repoUOM.ValueMember = "ID"; // inside form load event
repoUOM.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard; // inside form load event
```

```
private void RepoUOM_ProcessNewValue(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ProcessNewValueEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DisplayValue is string value && value.Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        var NewObject = new UnitName() { Name = value.Trim() };
        using (var db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            db.UnitNames.InsertOnSubmit(NewObject);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        ((List<UnitName>)repoUOM.DataSource).Add(NewObject); // exception thrown here
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to cast `repoUOM.DataSource` as type `List<UnitName>` and clearly it is not that type, or you would not be seeing that exception. If you expect to get a specific type out, you need to put that specific type in in the first place. Where are you setting that `DataSource` property in the first place? If you expect it to be a `List<UnitName>`, use a `List<UnitName>`.

Comment: That was really helpful , I forgot to cast the data source to List type , Thanks  
jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly cast a type like that unless it is supported through inheritance, covariance or an explicit type conversion is defined.

You could try explicitly casting to `Table<UnitName>` as that is the underlying type, see [Linq Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1?view=netframework-4.8.1) but the table is actually an `IListSource` and not actually a list, so you can't directly `Add` records to it, instead you need to `Append` or `Attach` them.

In this case I would use `Attach` so that `Append` doesn't track the record as a new record to later try to insert into the database.